# Redshift SQL - Window function trying to count events up to a certain date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a single SQL Statement (window function, CTE?) that would let me find out how many TFS tickets were 'open' each week (in the past), say 10 tickets were opened on '08/26/2019', 15 tickets opened in '09/06/2019, etc.
Basically, I am trying to answer the question:
"How many tickets are opened weekly for board='ABC'"?

Here is the regular query that let's me find this, however, I do not want to write code to run this on a loop for each week.
I feel there has to be a single query (with sub-queries) that would let me do this.

An open ticket for this board, means that at a certain point-in-time it wasn't 'Done' or 'Removed'.

```
SELECT wi.boardName, DATE_TRUNC('week', wi.changedDate::date)::date as week,
COUNT(distinct wi.id) AS openCount
FROM tfs.workitem_revisions wi
JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(rev) AS rev
    FROM tfs.workitem_revisions 
    WHERE UPPER(boardName) = UPPER('ABC')
    AND changedDate < '08/19/2019' --> I would have to do this for every week, trying not to
    GROUP BY 1
) wi2 ON (wi.id = wi2.id AND wi.rev = wi2.rev)
WHERE UPPER(wi.boardName) = UPPER('ABC')
AND UPPER(state) NOT IN (UPPER('Done'), UPPER('Removed'))
GROUP BY 1;
```

Current Data Set:
Each TFS ticket can have X amount of revisions (updates).
The tricky part is that for each ticket I have to limit it's revisions up to the week, in this case I am using each Monday as the start of a week.

```
Id      Revision State ChangedDate
23810   1   New 2019-04-04 23:47:19.0
23810   2   New 2019-04-04 23:47:28.0
23810   3   New 2019-04-05 09:09:21.0
23810   4   New 2019-04-05 09:39:26.0
23810   5   New 2019-04-09 12:31:23.0
23810   6   New 2019-04-12 06:59:42.0
23810   7   New 2019-04-12 09:40:28.0
23810   8   New 2019-04-15 01:07:12.0
23810   9   New 2019-04-19 12:47:21.0
23810   10  New 2019-05-01 14:33:59.0
23810   11  New 2019-05-01 14:51:20.0
23810   12  New 2019-05-02 10:55:01.0
23810   13  New 2019-05-02 11:58:22.0
23810   14  New 2019-05-14 14:59:37.0
23810   15  Coding  2019-05-14 15:11:38.0
23810   16  Coding  2019-05-14 15:11:44.0
23810   17  Coding  2019-05-14 15:14:02.0
23810   18  Coding  2019-05-14 15:48:20.0
23810   19  Coding  2019-05-14 15:49:25.0
23810   20  Code Complete   2019-05-14 15:49:28.0
23810   21  Code Complete   2019-05-14 16:58:39.0
23810   22  Code Complete   2019-05-15 02:23:07.0
23810   23  Code Complete   2019-05-15 04:05:23.0
23810   24  Code Complete   2019-05-15 04:05:23.0
23810   25  Deployed    2019-05-15 04:05:23.0
23810   26  Deployed    2019-05-15 04:31:15.0
23810   27  Deployed    2019-05-15 05:49:00.0
23810   28  Deployed    2019-05-15 05:49:00.0
23810   29  Deployed    2019-05-15 10:32:26.0
23810   30  Testing 2019-05-15 11:59:06.0
23810   31  Testing 2019-05-15 11:59:09.0
23810   32  Testing 2019-05-15 12:12:28.0
23810   33  Deployed    2019-05-15 15:40:08.0
23810   34  Deployed    2019-05-15 15:40:08.0
23810   35  Code Complete   2019-05-15 15:40:12.0
23810   36  Code Complete   2019-05-15 15:40:13.0
23810   37  Coding  2019-05-15 15:40:20.0
23810   38  Coding  2019-05-15 15:40:20.0
23810   39  Coding  2019-05-15 15:50:05.0
23810   40  Coding  2019-05-16 10:16:11.0
23810   41  Coding  2019-05-16 10:22:37.0
```

Desired result:

```
ABC 2019-08-12  61
ABC 2019-08-05  6
ABC 2019-07-29  1
ABC 2019-07-22  2
ABC 2019-07-15  2
ABC 2019-07-08  2
ABC 2019-07-01  1
ABC 2019-06-24  2
ABC 2019-06-17  53
ABC 2019-06-10  2
ABC 2019-05-27  1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I have edited the ticket to include sample data set for a single ticket, and desired results. I hope this makes it clear what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: So the real problem is that a ticket might be "open" during a week without any activity in the database and you still want to count it?

Comment: So if a ticket was in an open state anytime during that week, it gets counted as being open for that week.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `date_trunc()` and aggregation?

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', changedDate) as the_week, COUNT(DISTINCT wi.id) as openCount
FROM tfs.workitem_revisions 
WHERE UPPER(boardName) = UPPER('ABC') AND changedDate < '2019-08-19'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Yes, but for all weeks available in the data set, the filter I put there should really be removed.

Comment: I forgot to add in the query that I am using this statement to calculate things in a weekly basis starting on Mondays ```DATE_TRUNC('week', wi.changedDate::date)::date as week```.

Comment: Gordon was just basing the filter on the dates from your sample ouput. Obviously it's trivial for you to adjust as necessary. Subtracting on day from date before truncation will give you weeks that start on Monday. Just add back after truncate for the output.